# JBPM 7.43: How to handle selected change item in ListBox dynamically?

Tags: jboss, workflow, jbpm

I have a question about how to handle selected change item in ListBox when design TaskForm?

I would like to binding new value to other Listbox when the selected Listbox change value.

Anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [blog](https://pravinstechblog.blogspot.com/2020/07/how-to-load-data-dynamically-in-listbox.html) it will demonstrate how to load data dynamically in ListBox and how to load data based on the selection in other Listbox.

Comment: Thank you, But I want to that: When the selected Listbox 1 changes value, the Listbox 2 auto reload new data. Do you have any suggestion?